# Bootstrap Slider Caption Resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Full Slider Theme available [here](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/).  For some reason the text I used isn't re-sizing based on device.  When I view it on mobile about three letters take up the whole screen.  I'm using H1 and H2 (see snippet below).  It looks fine on a normal screen.  I've done a lot of searching and it seems like I should use a 'class="container-fluid"' and/or a 'class="row-fluid"'?  When I try this the slides go blank.   I'm wondering if I need to define new styles in the full-slider.css or if I'm doing something wrong or if this is intended behavior?  Any insight would be appreciated....

---

Sample

---

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7"></li>
            </ol>



            <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1 id="type">{{ scores.content.description }}</h1>
                        <h2 class="text-justify">{{ scores.content.general_description }}</h2></br>

                        <h2 style="text-align: center">Social Media.</h2>

                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin">
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> </a>

                            <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                        </div></br>
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="" style="color:white" target="_blank">Link 1</a> |
                            <a href="" style="color:white" target="_blank">Link 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wont resize itself since it is h1 and h2. so, Use custom styles to manipulate them.(using media queries will be a helpful solution.)

something like this:-

```
@media (max-width:767px)
{
    .carousel-caption> h1
    {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .carousel-caption> h2
    {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up finding this example which lead me to the @media. http://arturssmirnovs.com/blog/bootstrap-carousel-100-height-and-width/